# javascript slideshow not working?

Tags: javascript, html, image, web, slideshow

i have created a code for a simple javascript picture slideshow.
so, when i copy the code directly from the website that i learned it from it works. when i try to recreate the code exactly the same way, it does not work. how is this possible? i have revised the code thoroughly. is javascript not working or what? the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
    <title>Welcome!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var image1 = new Image()
            image1.src = "sample01.jpg"
        var image2 = new Image()
            image2.src = "sample02.jpg"
        var image3 = new Image()
            image3.src = "sample03.jpg"
        var image4 = new Image()
            image4.src = "sample04.jpg"
        var image5 = new Image()
            image5.src = "sample05.jpg"
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <img src="sample01.jpg" name="slider1" width=800 height=380 />
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var x=1;
        function slider()
        {
            document.images.slider1.src = eval("image"+x+".src");
            if (x<5)
                x++;
            else
                x=1;
            setTimeout=("slider()",10);
        }
        slider();
        </script>
    </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
setTimeout=("slider()",10);
```

by

```
setTimeout("slider()",10);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        var x=1;
        function slider()
        {
            document.images.slider1.src = eval("image"+x+".src");
            x= (x+1)%4 +1;
            setTimeout(slider,10);
        }
        setTimeout(slider,10); // 10 is too fast for a slide show (10ms) use at least 1000ms
```